# How to save 3D Model as .PNG

Tags: c#, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

I have a program, and when I press the button "add Catalog" I can add a catalog which contains many .obj files (3d models).

When I select the directory of the catalog I need to save the .obj as .png in a particular folder.

I am using helixtoolkit and I have already added the nuget packet and got everything else ready but just not the preview saver as .png.

https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/10564694/

Comment: So what *does* happen when you use your existing code? It looks like you already have the code to try to save it as a png...

Comment: No I dont have it actually. I dont know how to use the given functions of the .cs That´s why I am asking for help.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I'm sorry if that sounded so rude.

Answer (score 3):

The HelixViewport3D class ha as method called Export(). So when you define your Viewport in e.g. MainWindow.xaml like that:

```
<h:HelixViewport3D x:Name="MyViewport">
```

you can access the HelixViewport3D your MainWindow.xaml.cs and use the Export() function:

```
MyViewport.Export("<somepath>/img.png");
```

Comment: Oh that works for a single obj.Do you actually know if its a bit customizable ,so that I don´t even need the WPF Application to be open . So when I click in my main Form add catalog that all  x 50 different object datas get saved without opening the wpf form ?

Comment: The problem is that the Export() function renders the Viewport control to generate the image. You can try create a Viewport not in xaml but in a separate class without showing it. Then load and export each model.

Comment: Is it not possible to hide the WPF while it´s doing exactly this ?

Comment: So your program where you can add catalogs is not an wpf app?

Comment: The WindowForm we use to interact has an add catalog button ,we select an catalog which has folders with obj mtl and sometimes textures within a subfolder.The program should button press , create for every .obj an preview (.png )saved in a path.

Comment: So for me it looks like you need a obj to image converter. You can try write a console application which acceps as input a filepath or a list of filespath. It then loads one or multipe obj into a viewport and creates a snapshot.